# Find all strings of length 1 through N in String of length N

Tags: javascript, algorithm, performance

I'm trying to find all substrings within an string. That is, all strings of length 1 through N in a string of length N.

**Example**

```
N = '1079'
subStrings = [1,0,7,9,10,07,79,107,079,1079]
```

**First Attempt**

I have a solution that works on strings of relatively small N but on larger Ns the solution is extremely slow. Here's the current solution:

```
N = 'somestring'
l = N.length
k = 1
subStrings = []

while (k <= l) {
  i = 0
  while (i + k <= l) {
    subStrings.push(N.slice(i,k+i))
    i++
  } 
  k++
}

// subStrings is an array containing the substrings
```

How can I improve the performance of the algorithm to return all substrings?

Comment: what is `v` in your code? Specify the number which has slow result

Comment: Remnant from copying, updated.

Comment: Shouldn't the `subints` exclude `1079`? Also this question is about performance improvements of working code, which belong more on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: so, at what number's length it slows down?

Comment: It should include the full integer really, so maybe 'sub-integers' is a poor term.

Comment: @squint The approach makes sense, but I think it will be a little slower than the current algorithm.

Comment: if we talk about integers, what should be the resulting `subInts` array for the following number `10791001002` ? Or even better: `1000000001`

Comment: Can you show the long integer for which the algorithm is extremely slow?

Comment: Order of the sub-integers is not important. Duplicates need to be included. It makes it easier to consider the integer a string, and the output needs to be every sub-string of length 1-N. In a quick test the current algorithm takes several seconds for a string length of ~2500

Comment: @BrettDeWoody: Ah yeah, I forgot about duplicates cropping up naturally in the number. The dupes I was avoiding were with the overlapping substrings.

Comment: I don't see too many problems with the performance of your algorithm, every single loop generates a nessisary item to push into the array. The bottleneck here are the `push` and `slice` operations.

Comment: @Roman -https://gist.github.com/brettdewoody/b31855a404abc3e871e659aac62ab67b

Comment: Here's a quick example of a string with length ~2500 - http://codepen.io/brettdewoody/pen/yJzooq?editors=0011. Takes over a second to complete on average.

Comment: @BrettDeWoody Seem quicker in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4fb7sj3x/). JavaScript isn't the fastest language, and I don't think there is too much you can do staying in a browser. I'd say if you want the best performance you will want to run a parallel multi-threaded application taking advantage of the GPU (*such as CUDA*). Where each thread will execute the operation on `N-1` sub strings, or even `N-2`, `N-3`, ... sub strings depending on how many threads the computer can use. But that would be for extremely long strings.

Comment: @le_m The definition of 'integer' is 'a number that can be written without a fractional component'. Author never mentioned it being a `Number`.

Comment: @bezmax the given example assigns a `Number` literal to N, that's why I am wondering...

Comment: You might want to rephrase your question to e. g. "Find all subsequences of a string".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As other commenters have noted, there is not much to improve here. Here's probably the best possible javascript version, with two optimizations applied:

1. Changed `slice` to growing strings instead.

**Note:** this seems to only help with long sequences of numbers and small sets. After enough iterations, V8 makes enough warmup optimization for noslice to become faster than this "growing strings" method. See comments for discussion of this phenomenon.

2. <s>Changed `while` loop to `for` loop. For some reason this made it 100ms faster.</s> (It seems the increase in speed was because of an error in code, thanks @le_m for noticing)

```js
var start = new Date().getTime();

N = '23692719352345230452034523045823751925012830428043850348503834702834028305724087283409823058402897345982735402934579823750982734590123457239845723972345897234958732495872384957239846752397459327459238645972634598236452389457629346592387465923108457429386419659217834595873459872349576239487523947859872593487529384577823419823641829375412938742119482739107423481290734981236591206752871439071452398457213864957613593184721398471329874129083471293874219356129375421304712938743467812938461239561239874673291847129836451923865449825129873432874192837549281735892317432098491273498123675491238412635496213421394752369271935234523045203452304582375192501283042804385034850383470283402830572408728340982305840289734598273540293457982375098273459012345723984572397234589723495873249587238495723984675239745932745923864597263459823645238945762934659238746592310845742938641965921783459587345987234957623948752394785987259348752938457782341982364182937541293874211948273910742348129073498123659120675287143907145239845721386495761359318472139847132987412908347129387421935612937542130471293874346781293846123956123987467329184712983645192386544982512987343287419283754928173589231743209849127349812367549123841263549621342139475236927193523452304520345230458237519250128304280438503485038347028340283057240872834098230584028973459827354029345798237509827345901234572398457239723458972349587324958723849572398467523974593274592386459726345982364523894576293465923874659231084574293864196592178345958734598723495762394875239478598725934875293845778234198236418293754129387421194827391074234812907349812365912067528714390714523984572138649576135931847213984713298741290834712938742193561293754213047129387434678129384612395612398746732918471298364519238654498251298734328741928375492817358923174320984912734981236754912384126354962134213947523692719352345230452034523045823751925012830428043850348503834702834028305724087283409823058402897345982735402934579823750982734590123457239845723972345897234958732495872384957239846752397459327459238645972634598236452389457629346592387465923341084574293864196592178345958734598723495762394875239478598725934875293845778234198236418293754129387421194827391074234812907349812365912067528714390714523984572138649576135931847213984713298741290834712938742193561293754213047129387434678129384612395612398746732918471298364519238654498251298734328741928375492817358923174320984912734981236754912384126354962133243242139475';

l = N.length;
k = 1;
subInts = [];

for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
  num = "";
  for (k = 1; k < l-i+1; k++) {
    num += N.charAt(i+k-1);
    subInts.push(num);
  }
} 

var end = new Date().getTime();
var time = end - start;
document.body.textContent = 'Execution time: ' + time + '; Elements: ' + subInts.length;
```

Comment: I'm guessing branch prediction is why the for-loop is faster. The growing string idea was defiantly a good one :)

Comment: strange, this code shows me about ~4000 for `time` in Chrome v51

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest What about the original version? http://codepen.io/brettdewoody/pen/yJzooq?editors=0011

Comment: @bezmax, it has shown me `Execution time: 721` with `for` loops

Comment: For input `"123"` your code returns `["1", "12", "2"]` - writing `k < l-i+1` fixes that. Might explain the 100ms perf. improvement :)

Comment: @le_m Thanks, fixed the problem in code and you could be right about while and for. That means only one optimization remains.

Comment: @bezmax According to https://jsfiddle.net/sqhtzyyp/1/ the 'growing strings' seem to be slower than slicing at least on Chrome. Interestingly, `slice` is also faster than `substring`.

Comment: @le_m For shorter strings - correct. But for longer strings (which is original problem) 'growing strings' wins. For example with length 160 noslice becomes the winner: https://jsfiddle.net/njpj2wk3/ . Length 320 runs very long, but the results are these: "original x 627 ops/sec ±2.94% (88 runs sampled)
prealloc x 558 ops/sec ±0.83% (91 runs sampled)
noslice x 806 ops/sec ±1.91% (94 runs sampled)". So basically, the bigger the length - the faster it gets.

Comment: @bezmax That's interesting! I will add this to the benchmark

Comment: @le_m That means, growing a string has a lower complexity than slicing. I wonder why. It seems to me that both should be O(n) with n being an amount of copied characters. However, it may just be that browsers do some internal optimization of joining two strings saving it as some kind of lazily evaluated string maybe? That is, "a" + "b" does not create a new string "ab", but store it as () -> "a" + "b". But again, that is only my guess. You could try running a separate test where you check each character from the result set of all argorithms. If my theory is correct - noslice should be slowest.

Comment: @bezmax I ran your benchmark 10 times and slicing was faster 9 out of 10 times. Seems to be a warm-up issue with the V8 optimizing compiler.

Comment: @le_m Don't think so. Here's the latest test I run: https://jsfiddle.net/nuzd0pLz/ . Basically I took your test, increased the length of string and moved noslice to be the first test (so that it handles the warmup if that's an issue). Results on my PC: `noslice x 60.83 ops/sec ±15.96% (42 runs sampled) 
original x 18.25 ops/sec ±11.14% (35 runs sampled) 
prealloc x 18.62 ops/sec ±10.28% (35 runs sampled) 
Fastest is noslice`. Even if you take -15% into consideration for noslice and +11% for original, noslice still outperforms heavily for larger strings.

Comment: @bezmax I think I found the reason for our different benchmark results: If one performs a "warm-up" by calling each function a few times (e. g. looping over them 1000 times to be on the safe side), we can be pretty sure that at least on Chrome the V8 compiler replaced the code with an optimized variant. And it turns out that after optimization, slicing is faster than appending strings. However, for the unoptimized code, appending strings is faster. See https://jsfiddle.net/sqhtzyyp/5/ for the benchmark with "warm-up".

Comment: @le_m Yeah, seems that the mystery is solved. I will add this to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is **nothing you can do to dramatically improve your performance**. If you will look closer, you will see that for the string of length `n`, you will generate `n * (n + 1) / 2` elements. So your algorithm is `O(n^2)`.

For your 2500 length string, you will end up with approximately 6 mln operations. No wonder that your javascript takes more than a second to do that.

---

**P.S.** this is how I would implement it, you can test, may be it is a little bit faster.

```
arr = n.toString().split('')
l = arr.length
for (var i=0; i < l + 1; i++){
   for (var j = i + 1; j < l + 1; j++){
     console.log(arr.slice(i, j).join())
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation is already very fast. But there is one common technique you can use to improve the performance by about 10% (on Chrome / V8): **Preallocation**

We know that there will be `l * (l + 1) / 2` subsequences in total. Use that information to preallocate the `subStrings` array via `subStrings = new Array(l * (l + 1) / 2)` and replace `subStrings.push(...)` with `subStrings[n] = ...`:

```
function subsequences(s) {
  var l = s.length, n = 0, k = 1,
      result = new Array(l * (l + 1) * .5);

  while (k <= l) {
    var i = 0;
    while (i + k <= l) {
      result[n++] = s.slice(i, k + i);
      i++;
    } 
    k++;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Even though you introduce an additional counter variable, the performance gain by replacing a dynamically growing array with a static one is significant.

See https://jsfiddle.net/sqhtzyyp/5/ for a benchmark. Especially after a few runs - when the optimizing compiler kicks in - preallocation with slicing outperforms all other implementations (tested only on Chrome / Node / V8).

Performance comparison for different string length (16, 640 and 2447 characters) in Chrome:

[image]